# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Modal Window OnScroll Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, modal-dialog

I want to trigger something to fire functions inside Bootstrap modal window when user scroll page:

I've tried

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.modal-scrollable', function(){
CheckFunction(); 
});
```

and

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
CheckFunction();
});
```

with no luck. What may i do

Comment: just to confirm, on scrolling the main page, you want to do something inside the model?

Comment: Where is the code for CheckFunction()? Which part is not working (i.e. is the event listener not binding, is CheckFunction not working as expected, etc)? Be more specific and we may be able to help you

Comment: @shakirthow you are right but nearly. On scrolling inside modal dialog, i want to fire CheckFunction() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to fire something when the user scrolls the content inside the modal. then bind the scroll event to the modal content like this

```
$( ".modal-content" ).scroll(function() {
//fire event here
})
```

also set the `height` of the model content and set `overflow:scroll` that way the model becomes scrollable.

Comment: What do you mean from model? Is it modal?

Comment: hmm, it should work..this is the jsfiddle i used to test it.. on scroll it will change the text to red. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9svz5mus/2/)

Comment: Exquise me but it's not working for me. I see it's working example in jsfiddle . I think it's about my settings. I don't have that much time. I've added setInterval timer instead scroll listener for now. I will check problem later. Thank you @shakirthow

Comment: alright cool. maybe when you get a chance share a jsfiddle that way it will be easier to debug. cheers

Comment: I whould like to highlight the importance of setting the `height` and `overflow:scroll` CSS properties. The example is working for me.